# GCM firebase not showing APNs certificate in for IOS configuration

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have uploaded a .p12 file for IOS notification in GCM fire base. after uploading the file it is also showing "No certificate uploaded". please help in this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the certificate in this [iOS GCM link](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios) instead. Firebase uses FCM in the Firebase console so you might have chosen the wrong place.